# Did pilots use the radio in the Spanish Civil War?

Tags: safety, military, radio-communications, fighter, equipment

Was radio communication used by fighter pilots during the Spanish Civil War?
Fiat CR32, Messerschmitt Me 109 and Polikarpov I-16 were typical aircraft but I have no information about radio communication during dogfights. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 10):

The Heinkel 51s used in the Spanish Civil War had [radio equipment](https://tvd.im/aviation/1017-heinkel-he-51.html).  Messerschmidt Bf 109 versions A to E served in the conflict, the model B1 had [FuG 7 radios](http://www.aviation-history.com/messerschmitt/bf109.html).  I can't find a source but I'd guess that the 109 a had a FuG 2.

The [Fiat CR 32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_CR.32) had an RA 80-1 radio as an optional piece of equipment.

The Polikarpov I-16 was introduced into service in 1933 without a radio, but by 1939 [one had been fitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polikarpov_I-16#The_Far_East_and_battles_at_Khalkhin_Gol).

During the conflict, Werner Mölders developed a combat system that relied on radio co-ordination, there's an interesting article about that [here](https://theaviationgeekclub.com/the-story-of-werner-molders-the-luftwaffe-fighter-pilot-who-conceived-the-finger-four-formation/).

Comment: Thank you Dave. Very informative.